# Is geth / parity an on-chain or off-chain node?

Tags: go-ethereum, openethereum

I am drawing the architecture of a dapp but I cannot understand if the node (geth / parity) is in the on-chain or in the off-chain part.

Answer (score 1):

geth/parity implement the functionality of the nodes of the blockchain network and actually constitute the blockchain network